# Cakephp mail sending error

Tags: email, cakephp

I am getting the following error while sending mail from on localhost through my application:

> Strict (2048): Only variables should be passed by reference
>   [CORE\Cake\Network\Email\SmtpTransport.php, line 217]

The mail gets sent but an error is thrown and the screen does not redirect. I just want to get rid of this error.

I am posting the code from line 217 onwards.

```
        $response = end(explode("\r\n", rtrim($response, "\r\n")));

        if (preg_match('/^(' . $checkCode . ')(.)/', $response, $code)) {
            if ($code[2] === '-') {
                continue;
            }
            return $code[1];
        }
        throw new SocketException(__d('cake_dev', 'SMTP Error: %s', $response));
```

The email code is below.

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->config('gmail');
    $email->viewVars(array('userfname'=>$data['User']['username']));
    $email->viewVars(array('userlname'=>$data['User']['username']));
    $email->viewVars(array('username'=>$data['User']['username']));
    $email->template('welcome')
        ->emailFormat('html')
        ->sender('amitagarwal_dce@rediffmail.com', 'MyApp emailer')
        ->from(array('me@example.com' => 'CC'))
        ->to($data['User']['username'])
        ->bcc(array('atkral11@gmail.com'))
        ->subject('Thankyou for applying with us')
        ->send();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: @gabe3886 A really really old one, the buggy code shown was [**fixed in `2.0.4`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/87f5b6cf26b1a6efaf6be228bb9f70032f9f0212).

Comment: Are you not able to upgrade to 2.0.4 to correct this issue?

Comment: Upgrading to 2.0.4 solved the issue. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: 2.0.4 is old as old as the hills too, you should ideally upgrade to the latest release of the 2.7 branch. This will most likely require migrating some code, but it shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: I am not a developer per se. I have just learnt a little bit cakephp in order to make small changes myself. Will 2.7 result in significantly better performance? If so, I am willing to make the changes. If no, I would like to stick with the existing framework. Please advise.